# Python filtering out a list using elements from another list

Tags: python, list, filter

I am trying to filter out a list using another list. However, the elements of the list I am using to filter the other list is not identical strings. Please see my example as it will make more sense:

```
mylist = ['14001IB_L1P0', '14001OB_L1P1', '14002IB_L3P0', '14003OB_L1P1', '14001OB_L2P0']
remove_list = ['14001', '14002']
```

I want to remove the values from mylist that start with the values from remove_list.
I have tried doing this:

```
filtered_mylist = mylist[:]

for x in remove_list:
    for i in filtered_mylist:
        if x in i:
            print('remove ' +i)
            filtered_mylist.remove(i)
        else:
            print('keep '+i)
```

However, this is the result:

```
remove 14001IB_L1P0
keep 14002IB_L3P0
keep 14003OB_L1P1
remove 14001OB_L2P0
keep 14001OB_L1P1
remove 14002IB_L3P0
```

and this is what filtered_mylist consists of:

```
['14001OB_L1P1', '14003OB_L1P1']
```

However, it **should** consist of only 1 element:
`['14003OB_L1P1']`

It seems to me that for some reason, the loop has skipped over '14001OB_L1P1', the second element in the first loop. Why has this happened?

Comment: Don't remove the items from the list on which your are currently iterating, this will cause some items to be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one liner

```
mylist = list(filter(lambda x: all([x.find(y) != 0 for y in remove_list]), mylist))

#Output
['14003OB_L1P1']
```

The `all([x.find(y) != 0 for y in remove_list])` will return `True` if and only if `x` does not start with a single value from `remove_list`.

`all()` means all have to be `True`. `x.find(y) != 0` means `x` does not begin with `y`.

The rest is just executing the filter.

Comment: Thanks! This looks to have worked. And I like that it's contained within 1 line. It's too complicated for me to understand though. Would you mind explaining how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```py
remove_final = []
keep_final = []
for element in mylist:
    if any([element.startswith(x) for x in remove_list]):
        print(f'remove {element}')
        remove_final.append(element)
    else:
        print(f'keep {element}')
        keep_final.append(element)
```

Output:

```py
remove 14001IB_L1P0
remove 14001OB_L1P1
remove 14002IB_L3P0
keep 14003OB_L1P1
remove 14001OB_L2P0
```

And final lists:

```py
keep_final
['14003OB_L1P1']

remove_final
['14001IB_L1P0', '14001OB_L1P1', '14002IB_L3P0', '14001OB_L2P0']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code help you.

```
mylist = ['14001IB_L1P0', '14001OB_L1P1', '14002IB_L3P0', '14003OB_L1P1', '14001OB_L2P0']
remove_list = ['14001', '14002']

filtered_mylist = mylist[:]

for x in remove_list:

    i = 0
    while i < len(filtered_mylist):
        if x in filtered_mylist[i]:
            print('remove ' + filtered_mylist[i])
            filtered_mylist.remove(filtered_mylist[i])
        else:
            print('keep '+ filtered_mylist[i])
            i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method - append method.

Try to use "filter function + append" to do this instead of remove. That's much safer.

```py
mylist = ['14001IB_L1P0', '14001OB_L1P1', '14002IB_L3P0', '14003OB_L1P1', '14001OB_L2P0']
remove_list = ['14001', '14002']


def is_valid(item):
    for pattern in remove_list:
        if item.startswith(pattern):
            return False
    return True


res = []
for item in mylist:
    if is_valid(item):
        res.append(item)
print(res)
```